# Serializing Django Model and including further information for ForeignKeyField + OneToOneField

Tags: python, django

Using Django 1.7.

I have a model class `Topic` that I want to serialize. `Topic` has an attribute `Creator` that is a ForeignKey to a class `UserProfile`. The output from serialization gives me the following string:

```
'{"fields": {"building": 1, "title": "Foobar", "created": "2015-02-13T16:14:47Z", "creator": 1}, "model": "bb.topic", "pk": 2}'
```

I want `key` "creator" to say the username of associated with `UserProfile` (as opposed to right now, where it is giving me the pk value associated with `UserProfile`. The username is held within a OneToOneField with `django.contrib.auth.models` class `User`.

I tried to implement a UserProfileManager, but either I have done it incorrectly or the following is not an appropriate strategy:

```
def get_by_natural_key(self, user, picture, company):
    return self.get(user_id=user.id, user_pk=user.pk, username=user.get_username, picture=picture, company=company)
```

Finally, I looked around SO and found pointers to this: https://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers but it says it was last updated in 2011 so I am assuming there is something else out there.

Thanks. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you haven't implemented all the code needed to serialize the `UserProfile` with a natural key.

Actually the `get_by_natural_key` method is called when deserializing an object. If you want it to be serialized with a natural key instead of `pk` you should provide the `natural_key` method to the model.

Something like:

```
class UserProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, user, company):
        return self.get(user__user__username=user, company=company)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    objects = UserProfileManager()

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.user.name, self.company)
```

Now, if you serialize a `Topic` instance:

```
import django.core.serializers

obj = serializers.serialize('json', Topic.objects.all(), indent=2, use_natural_foreign_keys=True, use_natural_primary_keys=True)
```

you should get an output similar to:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "building": 1,
    "title": "Foobar",
    "created": "2015-02-13T16:14:47Z",
    "creator": [
      "dummy",
      "ACME Inc."
    ]
  }, 
  "model": "bb.topic", "pk": 2
}
```

supposing a *dummy* user exist with a company named *ACME Inc.* in its user profile.

Hope this helps.